# HBase warns with totalCompactingKVs less than currentCompactedKVs

Tags: hbase

In RegionServer logs there are a lot of warn messages with

```
compactions.CompactionProgress: totalCompactingKVs=N less than currentCompactedKVs=K
```

How could it be and are there any signifcant problems which can lead to such a behaviour?